# Dynamic change of drop down in php my sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two drop downs .one have static value and second get values from db. I want to that if value is selected from 1st drop down then relevant values loaded in 2nd drop down. I have tried. but its load all the data from database according to user.for example when user select from request type dropdown having value inquiry.then 2nd drop down load only the values which have catType Inquiry.and if he select the complaint then complaint data must be shown.I have been tried but all the data is loaded ,or only one data is loading.any body help me in this regard.Thanks in Advance.
Here is My Code

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
<label for="requesttype"><?php echo $requestField; ?></label>
 <select class="form-control" required="" id="requesttype" name="requesttype" onchange="fcrActionChange(this);">                      
 <option value="">Select Request Type</option>
 <option value="Inquiry">Inquiry</option>
<option value="Complaint">Complaint</option>
<option value="Service Request/FCR">Service Request/FCR</option>
<option value="Verification Call">Verification Call</option>
 </select>
<span class="help-block"><?php echo $requestHelp; ?></span>
  </div>
   </div>


<script type="text/javascript">


$("#requesttype").change(function() {
 $("#catId).load("navigation.php?requesttype=" + $("#requesttype").val());
   });
    </script>

     <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
  <label for="catId"><?php echo $categoryField; ?></label>
  <select class="form-control" name="catId" id="catId">
  $tcat = "SELECT catId, catName FROM categories WHERE userId = ".$userId." AND isActive = 1 AND catType = ".$_GET['requesttype'];
 $rest = mysqli_query($mysqli, $tcat) or die('-2'.mysqli_error());
 while ($tcatrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rest)) { 
   echo "<option value="$tcatrow['catId'] >";
   echo     clean($tcatrow['catName'])."</option>";
 }
 </select>
 <span class="help-block"><?php echo $categoryHelp; ?></span>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You use ajax for this type of problem

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI would you have some example.

Comment: There appear to be tutorials showing a variety of ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code won't work is because PHP is server-side. All of your PHP code is executed **once**, which is when your page loads. This is why you can't simply use PHP to load something dynamically without reloading the page. Your best option would be to use a client-side language like Javascript, possibly in conjunction with PHP.

One way you could do this:

1. Create a file, `getter.php` that does the database work, receiving the input (choice of first dropdown) via GET and returns data as `option` tags

```
<?php
    $tcat = "SELECT catId, catName FROM categories WHERE userId = ".$userId." AND isActive = 1 AND catType = ".$_GET['request_type];
    $rest = mysqli_query($mysqli, $tcat) or die('-2'.mysqli_error());
    while ($tcatrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rest)) { 
      echo "<option value=\"$tcatrow['catId'] >";
      echo     clean($tcatrow['catName'])."</option>";
    }
```

2. If you're using jQuery (which you probably should), you could use the `load()` function to call your `getter.php` with the proper parameters.

   ```
   //Assuming you give the first select id="request-type"and the second id="cat-id"
   $("#request-type").change(function() {
   $("#cat-id).load("getter.php?request_type=" + $("#request-type").val());
    });
   ```

For more details, see [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/dynamic-dropdowns/) (it actually explains three different ways of achieving your goal).

Comment: as i want that when 1st drop down value changes then 2nd should get the values from db according to 1st drop down selection.1st drop down has statict values

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @m.usman what did you put in navigation.php? And you still haven't indicated if you included jQuery properly.

Comment: Also, when you update your code in your question, don't replace the original code. Write "**EDITED:**" then add your updated code

Comment: navigation is the same page name .i am writing this on same page.and how to call this when select the request type

Answer (score 0):

You can use Php mysql and Ajax: 
http://demos.codexworld.com/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-php/